# Azure Iot Hub Device Provision System with mqtt

Tags: azure, certificate, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-dps

I'm trying to understand if I can use **mqtt** to handle provisioning of my device via the *Device Provision System*. 
Not much to read about that but what I have found is that you should connect to `global.azure-devices-provisioning.net`.

I'm wondering what the next step would be, i.e. what topic to publish/register to ?

Lets say I have created a device specific UUID that will be matched on the DPS when the device signs in via **mgtt** by some topic !! 
After that I expect the device to receive a signed device certificate via some other topic !!

Can somebody lay out the topics for achieving this ? (if possible at all)

Comment: Have you worked through this doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/iot-dps-mqtt-support

Comment: Glad to hear it! I made an answer so it’s easier for people to see

Comment: @EinarMar, don't forget to mark silent's answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

This official article describes how to use MQTT in conjunction with the Device Provisioning Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/iot-dps-mqtt-support